# Middleware returns 400 error when JSON is deserialized

Tags: asp.net-core, json-deserialization, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a very simple middleware:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
  if(await CheckIfRequestIsAuthorize(context))
  {
   await next.Invoke(context);
  }
}

private async Task<bool> CheckIfRequestIsAuthorize(HttpContext context)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Inside method");
  string requestBody = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

  dynamic tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
  string sessionId = (string)tmp.sessionId;

  if(sessionId == "string")
  {
    return true;
  } else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

// this is my controller and class

public class MyOwnRequest
{
  public string SessionId { get; set; }
  public string SpecialKey { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostMethod([FromBody] MyOwnRequest myOwnRequest)
{
  return Ok("It's okey");
}
```

When I make a request I get an error:
"The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true.

```
Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
```

I figure out that the problem is with this part of the code because when we do:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
  string requestBody = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
  await next.Invoke(context);
}
```

It's also caused an issue, maybe someone had a similar problem?

Body:

```
{
  "sessionId": "string",
  "specialKey": "string"
}
```

Edit:

I figure out that I need to enable to double read body of my request. But why I should do it? When a method is before `next.invoke` it should be called only once time.

Comment: You didn't adjust the position of pointer after reading the stream

Answer (score 1):

I tried as below:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
  var request = context.Request;
  request.EnableBuffering();
  var stream = request.Body;
  long? length = request.ContentLength;
  if(length!=null&length>0)
  {
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    var jsonstr = reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
    dynamic tmp =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstr);
    string sessionId = (string)tmp.SessionId;
  }

 context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
 await next.Invoke();
});
```

Result:

[image: Result]

If you don't adjust the position of the pointer:

[image: Pointer]